# Magento: add configurable products to cart programmatically

Tags: magento

**How to add the child product to cart programmatically?**

I've a child product `SKU`, I want to

1. Fetch the supper attributes *like* `size` and `color id` and values from the products,
2. Then fetch the parent `product id`,
3. Pass the super attributes on param with quantity, to add to `function cart`.

`//$cart->addProduct($product1, $options);`

Here, how to pass the supper attributes on the `$option` variable? Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this. I think it may need some improvements but it works good in simple cases.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());
// check if something is returned
if (!empty(array_filter($parentIds))) {
    $pid = $parentIds[0];

    // Collect options applicable to the configurable product
    $configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
    $productAttributeOptions = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configurableProduct);
    $options = array();

    foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
        $allValues = array_column($productAttribute['values'], 'value_index');
        $currentProductValue = $_product->getData($productAttribute['attribute_code']);
        if (in_array($currentProductValue, $allValues)) {
            $options[$productAttribute['attribute_id']] = $currentProductValue;
        }
    }

    // Get cart instance
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
    $cart->init();
    // Add a product with custom options
    $params = array(
        'product' => $configurableProduct->getId(),
        'qty' => 1,
        'super_attribute' => $options
    );
    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setData($params);
    $cart->addProduct($configurableProduct, $request);
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $cart->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try.

```
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $cart->addProduct($productCollection , 
                                        array( 'product_id' => $productId,
                                                 'qty' => 1,
                                                 'options' => array( $optionId => $optionValue));
    $cart->save();
```